# Python: allow class objects only in specific chain-able functions

Tags: python

My basic setup is, that I have a class (I call it `Special`) that should only be used inside specific functions of another class (I call it `AllowsSpecial`). I realized it the following way:

```py
class AllowsSpecial:
    _special_allowed = False

    def __init__(self):
        AllowsSpecial._special_allowed = True

    def func1(self, *args):
        # ... do something with Special
        AllowsSpecial._special_allowed = False
        return

    def func2(self, *args):
        # ... do something different with Special
        AllowsSpecial._special_allowed = False
        return


class Special:
    def __init__(self):
        if AllowsSpecial._special_allowed is False:
            raise Exception("Special can only be used in functions of AllowsSpecial()")
```

with that it is ok to do something like

```py
AllowsSpecial().func1(Special())
```

but if I do for example:

```py
sp = Special()
```

it will raise an exception. So far so good...

Now I would also like the functions `func1` and `func2` to be chain-able. This would mean at first that `func1` and `func2` would return `self` and than I would like to do something like:

```py
AllowsSpecial().func1(Special()).func2(Special())
```

with the current setup this would obviously fail because `func1` resets the `_special_allowed` allowed variable to `False`.

The only solution I came up with was using a Helper Class like this

```py
class Also:
    @property
    def also(self):
        return AllowsSpecial()
```

that returns a new `AllowsSpecial()` object. Then instead of returning `self` in `func1` and `func2` I would `return Also()`

than I would at least be able to do that:

```
AllowsSpecial().func1(Special()).also.func2(Special())
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could do it without the intermediate `Also` class?

Comment: This seems a horrible pattern to use. Please explain the deeper problem you hope to solve with this? What if code has `AllowsSpecial(); Special()`?

Comment: @trincot oh yes that actually a good point :) In general the problem is that I have a class that should only be used with a set of given functions, because it uses some global state that is taken care of by this functions. But if used outside they would mess with this state. So the general idea was to throw an exception whenever someone tries to use this class not in the predefined functions to prevent errors ...

Comment: *some global state*: bad idea. Encapsulate your state. But this is all too vague. Impossible to answer without very concrete use case.